# How to add caption for each pie chart (creating with tikzpicture) in tabular environment?

Tags: captions, pgf-pie

I have created the following figure in tabular environment for two different pie charts. But I am unable to give caption to each of them in their respective cell.
[image]

I used the following code and I was only able to add caption the way it is depicted in the figure. Kindly help.

```
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\newcommand\mycom[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}

\begin{table}[h]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
     \hline

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,line join=round]
  \pie [rotate = 180]
    {57/A,
    5/B,
    3/C,
    9/D,
    3/E,
    22/F,
    1/G}
\end{tikzpicture}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,line join=round]
  \pie [rotate = 180]
    {60/A,
    5/B,
    2/C,
    10/D,
    2/E,
    20/F,
    1/G}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{figure}{Pie Chart}
\label{samples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `subcaption` package. And there is no need to use a `table` environment just because you use a `tabular` inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}

\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|W{c}{0.45\textwidth}|W{c}{0.45\textwidth}|}
     \hline
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.44\linewidth}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,line join=round]
  \pie [rotate = 180]
    {57/A,
    5/B,
    3/C,
    9/D,
    3/E,
    22/F,
    1/G}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{A pie chart.}
\end{subfigure}
&
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.44\linewidth}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,line join=round]
  \pie [rotate = 180]
    {60/A,
    5/B,
    2/C,
    10/D,
    2/E,
    20/F,
    1/G}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Another pie chart.}
\end{subfigure}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pie charts.}
\label{samples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much mate. Cheers

Comment: Could you please notice and help regarding that subcaptions are not perfectly aligned? Is there a way that it could be possible to align them?

Comment: @Anees Sure. You can add an alignment key to the subfigures. I did that now, is this alignment what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thumbs up